# Are there any practical differences in fitting a random slope vs. fitting an interaction term in the intercept in lmer

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, misspecification

I am trying to fit a few models with the form

`Model A. lmer(DV ~ Predictor1 (continuous) * predictor2 (categorical with 4 levels) * (ot + ot2 + ot3 + ot4 = orthogonal polynomials) + (ot + ot2 + ot3 | Video ID) + (ot + ot2 + ot3 | participant ID), REML = FALSE)`

In this case participant ID have 70 levels, video has 56, predictor 1 only has one data point per participant whereas the ot polynomials are powers of time (with about 77 data points). Participant sees all videos and levels of Predictor 2.

I am able to fit that model reasonably well. However, when I try to for  random slope for predictor 2 (to make a "maximal" model) like:
`Model B. lmer(DV ~ Predictor1 * predictor2  * (ot + ot2 + ot3 + ot4) + (ot + ot2 + ot3 | Video ID) + (ot + ot2 + ot3 + predictor 2 | participant ID), REML = FALSE)`

or

`Model C. lmer(DV ~ Predictor1 * predictor2 * (ot + ot2 + ot3 + ot4) + (ot + ot2 + ot3 | Video ID) + (ot + ot2 + ot3 | participant ID) + (Predictor2| participant ID) , REML = FALSE)`

things get really slow (like days, or even a week or so, conversion is not guaranteed), this is even when using the `control = lmerControl(optimizer = "nloptwrap", calc.derivs = FALSE)`

I saw some models that are fitted with an interaction intercept instead, and considered fitting this which in my previous experience might be slightly faster

`Model D. lmer(DV ~ Predictor1 * predictor2 * (ot + ot2 + ot3 + ot4) + (ot + ot2 + ot3 | Video ID) + (ot + ot2 + ot3 | participant ID) + (ot + ot2 + ot3 | participant ID: Predictor2) , REML = FALSE)`
or

`Model D. lmer(DV ~ Predictor1 (continuous) * predictor2 (categorical with 4 levels) * (ot + ot2 + ot3 + ot4 = ortogonal (polynomials) + (ot + ot2 + ot3 | Video ID) + (ot + ot2 + ot3 | participant ID) + (1| participant ID: predictor2) , REML = FALSE)`

But I am not sure what are the implications of this? are Model C and Model D or E equivalent?

Thanks, any help is very much appreciated